# What is Ruby's OpenSSL::HMAC.new in JS?

Tags: node.js, ruby, openssl

I have some sample code for an API, but it's in Ruby, whereas I'd prefer to use nodeJS. Could you any of you kind ruby/JS chaps let me know what the JS equivalent would be, and any npm libraries I would need to install.

```
 hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.new(sharedsecret, OpenSSL::Digest::SHA512.new)
 signature = hmac.update(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

hmac = crypto.createHmac('SHA512', sharedsecret);
hmac.update(url);
signature = hmac.digest('hex');
```